# Why does fuzzywuzzy not consider character order

Tags: python, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

Consider this example:

```
>> from fuzzywuzzy import process
>> choices = ['account', 'update', 'query']
>> process.extract('u', choices)
[('account', 90), ('update', 90), ('query', 90)]
```

In the above case, it's confusing for my end-users that *account* is ranked above *update* for the given string. In this case *account* happens to be arbitrarily placed in front due to list order, since all matches share the same score. However, I would have imagined that *update* would have a higher score simply because the character **u** shows up earlier in the string.

Is this a conceptual error or am I not using the correct scorer here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all you are using a "bad" scorer. Based on your scores you are probably using difflib. You should switch to the `python-Levenshtein` based implementation. This can be done with the `scorer` parameter.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

def MyScorer(s1, s2):
    fratio = fuzz.ratio(s1, s2)
    fratio -= (s2.find(s1)*5)
    return fratio

choices = ['account', 'update', 'query']
dex = process.extract('u', choices, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
mex = process.extract('u', choices, scorer=MyScorer)
print("Default Scorer:", dex)
print("MyScorer:", mex)
```

Now the output is

`[('query', 33), ('update', 29), ('account', 25)]`

Which is better, but `Levenshtein` didn't really care about the position,

> Levenshtein distance (LD) is a measure of the similarity between two strings, which we will refer to as the source string (s) and the target string (t). The distance is the number of deletions, insertions, or substitutions required to transform s into t.

that's why i added the definition for `MyScorer()` where you can implement your own algorithm which takes the position into account. I also added a example of an implementation which takes the position into account (but i'm not really experienced at designing such algorithms, so don't expect this one to be perfect or even usable). Anyway, the output of MyScorer is:

`[('update', 29), ('query', 28), ('account', 5)]`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm curious though - isn't this the natural  behavior for most fuzzy searches? For instance, using **CMD + SHIFT + P** in Sublime Text/Visual Studio Code and typing *u* will highlight the *u* character in commands, but it always presents the commands that start with *u* first.

Comment: I guess they either created their own fuzzy matching algorithm, or they just used a different library. [fuzzyset](https://github.com/axiak/fuzzyset) seems to do a pretty good job out of the box, you might want to try that. (Don't use the pip package, it's outdated! Download the github repo and easy_install it)

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
process.extract('u', choices)
```

You don't pass the scorer function to extract method. The method will choose the max ratio of 4 soccer to you.

> - base_ratio : The Levenshtein Distance of two string.
> - partial_ratio : The ratio of most similar substring.
> - token_sort_ratio : Measure of the sequences' similarity sorting the token before comparing.
> - token_set_ratio : Find all alphanumeric tokens in each string.

In your case, the origin string is `u`, and target string is `account`,`update`,`query`.
The basic ratio is `account : 25`, `update : 29`, `query : 33`.
The partial ratio all is 90.
And the token sort ratio and token set ratio all is 85.5.
So the max ratio of each string is 90.
So you get the output `[('account', 90), ('update', 90), ('query', 90)]`.

Answer (score 0):

"process.extract" find best matches in a list or dictionary of choices, return a list of tuples containing the match and it's score. It does not depend on "Position" of choices in the list or dictionary.